# Play any video in flash in stream(Blob) format in javascript

Tags: javascript

```html
FB.ui(
 {
 method: 'feed',
 name: 'Local Host checker',
 link: 'http://my ip address<s:url action='downappsuservideo'><s:param name="id" value="8"></s:param></s:url>',
 description: 'Maurya  sibggggg',
 message: 'messagecc',
     //type: 'video',
 });
 });
 });
</script>
```

I want to play  a video that is stored in database in blob format .That video must play in flash using javascript. When i used above code then video file is start downloading,but want to play video in facebook page using sharing concept of facebook.

Comment: what you have tried?

Comment: @Soorapadman please help me

Comment: @naveenmaurya We are not here to write the code for you. What have you tried, what code isn't working, why do you even _need_ to use flash for this and might it not be a better idea to use a `video` element with a blob converted to base64 as source? Also, why is a _video_ stored as a _blob_ in your database? This must take up an inordinate amount of space compared to simply using it as a video file.